# Simulate next click on INSTFILES page to take user to a Custom Page (NSIS)

Tags: nsis

This is my use case:

I'm creating an uninstaller using NSIS.
I'm in the "MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES" page during the uninstallation flow.
Files got removed in the "Section Uninstall" code.
Now I need the user to be taken to a custom page, by simulating the next button click in "MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES".
I did check for "MUI_UNFINISHPAGE_NOAUTOCLOSE", but I don't have it defined in my code. Still it is not automatically moving to the next page.

This is the code where the pages are defined for the uninstaller:

```
UninstPage custom un.UninstConfirm_Show ;1st page (custom page)
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES ;2nd page
UninstPage custom un.UninstFinish_Show ;3rd & final page (custom page)
```

I need to move from 2nd page to 3rd page without user clicking on the next button in the 2nd page.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to simulate clicking the Next button:

```
GetDlgItem $0 $HWNDPARENT 1
SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_COMMAND} 1 $0
```

FYI: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=187143

Comment: I did try this before, but it was not working.
Anyways I worked around it by calling `un.UninstFinish_Show` at the end of `Section Uninstall`. Thanks for your inputs Slappy.

Comment: Assuming un.UninstFinish_Show is a nsDialogs page, this is not really the correct solution, you should not force a page to display like that.

Comment: Hi Slappy. Yeah I'm accepting answers that is working for me. And some of them, I have to try it out because I already took alternate approach by the time I got answers. Anyways I really appreciate you two helping me with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

MUI calls `SetAutoClose true` in `un.onGUIInit` when the MUI finish page is used but you can just call `SetAutoClose true` in a **uninstaller section** to achieve the same effect.